# NodeJS Child process cannot access MySQL Pool object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, child-process, mysql-connector

My intention is upon a file upload the main Node.JS Express backend process will fork a child process which will call a java program to parse the uploaded file and then the NodeJS child will make bulk (100K+) MySQL queries. I want the child to handle the queries because I do not want the parent process to "block." Since both the parent and child processes need access to the MySQL connection I have defined in an external file containing an `npm mysql` pool.

`mysqlConnector.js:`

```
// Load module
var mysql = require('mysql');
// Initialize pool
var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host     : 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'bob',
    password: 'my_pass',
    database: 'my_db'
});    

const doQuery = (query_string) => {
  console.log(pool);
  pool.query(query_string, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('in doQuery: query' );
  });
};

exports.doQuery = doQuery;
exports.pool = pool
```

My index.js (main process) is able to access this pool and make queries with no issue. The main process will fork the child running the following code

`handleprops.js:`

```
const {execSync, fork} = require('child_process');
const {doQuery} = require('../mysqlConnector');

const exec_options = {
    cwd: null,
    env: null,
    encoding: 'utf8',
    timeout: 0,
    maxBuffer: 200 * 1024,
    killSignal: 'SIGTERM'
};


process.on('message', msg=>{

  if(msg.filepath && msg.username){
    execSync(`java -jar C:\\Users\\colli\\d2reader\\out\\artifacts\\d2reader_jar\\d2reader.jar ${msg.filepath}`, exec_options);

    var filename = msg.filepath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    filename = __dirname + "\\json\\" + filename.substring(0, filename.length-3) + "json";
    try{
      const fs = require('fs');
      const data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      processSharedStashQueries(JSON.parse(data), msg.username);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    process.exit();
  }
});

const processSharedStashQueries = (data, username) => {
    const INSERT_USER_QUERY = `insert into sharedstashes  (NumStashes, SharedGold, NumItems, UserID) values (${data.numStashes}, ${data.sharedGold}, ${data.numItems}, (select id from users where username = '${username}'))`;
    doQuery(INSERT_USER_QUERY);

};
```

When the child calls `doQuery()` inside `processSharedStashQueries()` the pool object will be logged and I can verify it is a valid and defined object and is the same exact pool object the parent process uses. However, nothing happens when the child hits the `pool.query()` line of code. No error and no console logs. It's as if nothing happens.

Why can the child process "see" the pool object but not be able to use it?

Is my overall approach incorrect? I fear I might be missing some knowledge in how to use npm mysql effectively to do such a thing. Should I put the MySQL query smarts inside the external java program? Or is that bad design?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: suppose the `pool` requires `pool.connect()` after createPool, do you have the connect call in index.js? and do you have it in the child process?

Comment: An explicit `connect()` call is not necessary with pools. I am able to use the pool successfully in `index.js` by importing `const {doQuery, pool} = require('./mysqlConnector');` Then I am able to successfully execute `doQuery()` from `index.js` (unlike the child). I am also able to use the pool object directly in `index.js`